# Can I label a worker node before joining Kubernetes master?

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to prepare multiple yaml files customizing arguments of flannel (DaemonSet) and run the flannel pod of the node with yaml matching the condition expressed by the label. Can I label a worker node before joining Kubernetes master ?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `--node-labels` when you're `kubelet` is starting, which will apply the labels to the nodes; but **ONLY** during registration.

This will not work if your `kubelet` is starting up and the node is already a member of the cluster.

[Kubelet Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will proceed with the following procedure.

1) Deploy multiple yaml files (DaemonSet) with variations of flanneld's arguments.  
2) Join a node to K8s master. A flannel pod suitable for this node is not yet deployed.  
3) Label this node and deploy a pod from flannel yaml (DaemonSet) matching the condition of this label.